# How to rotate SVG image using Shell script in linux

Tags: bash, svg

I want to generate SVG image using shell script in Linux. everything is ok. But how to insert transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)" in to script.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html> 
  <head>
  <title>SVG</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <svg width="1028px" height="728px">
  <rect fill="#FACE8D" x="0" y="0" width="1028px" height="728px" rx="10"
  ry="10"  stroke="green" stroke-width="8" />
  <text x="150pt" y="300pt" fill="red" font-
  size="40pt" transform="translate(30) rotate(45
  50 50)" stroke="#000000" >some text</text>
  </svg>

  </body>
  </html>"
```

But thing is when translate function call inside shell script I got error. Due to the "(" ")" .then I tried with transform="translate\(30\) rotate\(45,50 50\)" But does not work neither.so how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Quick way is just to use echo 'markup' instead of echo "markup", so it doesn't get interpreted.